# How to register a desktop application (app) for Windows Error Reporting (WER)

Tags: desktop-application, windows-error-reporting

I have a sysdev.microsoft.com account.  There used to be an app that you download and install that would allow you to scan your desktop app and submit it to sysdev so you can receive windows error reports. I can't find it anymore (use to be a link in the dashboard).

So now how do you register a desktop application with sysdev so you can receive WER reports in the dashboard/report section?

Any searches I do all I get is the WER API and references to hardware devices.

Answer (score 3):

OK I found it.  The app is the "Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange client" or also called Product mapping tool.

You find it by logging into sysdev.  Then click on reports on the left.  Then scroll to the very bottom of the page there is heading called Downloads.  Under that a link called "Product Mapping Tool".

It's been three years since I used it so I forgot where it was.  The location hasn't changed; I just forgot where it was and what it was called.

This helped me figure it out again: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2012/03/28/windows-hardware-dashboard-reports-faq.aspx#filemap.

Comment: This information remains accurate in 2016. Here's a direct link to the "Reports" page described by @Wes:
https://sysdev.microsoft.com/en-AU/Hardware/member/Telemetry/Default.aspx
Look for the "Product Mapping Tool" link as described.